# PDF created by Google Scripts and sent as an email attachment is unreadable

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, gmail, pdf-generation, email-attachments

I'm trying to copy a document I have in my drive, save it as a PDF, and then email the PDF as an attachment. However, even though the PDF is always copied and sent correctly as an attachment, and is properly readable form the gmail "preview" when viewing the email chain, it is unreadable when downloaded (filetype is simply "file"). Both the original document, when viewed from my drive, and the PDF (when the document is saved as a PDF and downloaded from the drive) are readable.

To me this indicates that there is either a problem with the way I convert the document into a PDF, or the way I attach it.

Here is how I convert it to a PDF:

```
var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'));
```

And here is how I attach it:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {
    name : "senderEmail",
    attachments : [invoicePdf]
});
```

I know that using the `Document` Google Scripts class it is possible to get a Document as a pdf using the `application/pdf` keyword.

I have been sending emails with attached PDFs in this manner for a while now to several people; I find it unlikely, but possible, that none of them brought this issue to my attention until recently. The attachments from both recent emails (from people who have confirmed to me that the attachments are unreadable) and older emails are unreadable for my when I go to those conversations in my gmail and download the attached PDFs.

Comment: You create a pdf as `newFile` and send a different file called `invoicePdf` in the above code. So wondering if there are intermediate steps that modify the file?

Comment: The PDF created as `newFile` is returned in one function, and `invoicePdf` is, in a separate function, set as the value returned by the function that returns `newFile`.

Comment: I tried the above code and it worked just fine for me!

Comment: Try modifying your this line as follows ::: var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf')).setName("fileName.pdf");

Comment: @Umair: Tried that, and it works. It seems the key is ensuring that the .pdf file has ".pdf" at the end of its name.

Comment: @LeonardotheVinchi I have added this in the answer, you can accept that as solution/upvote so that people checking this afterwards can understand that this is working. Thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly change your this line

```
var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf'));
```

as follows

```
var newFile = DriveApp.createFile(copyFile.getAs('application/pdf')).setNa‌​me("fileName.pdf");
```

So that drive name it with .pdf extension, so that it can be opened properly.